# How to hide keyboard even when uitextfield is firstresponder?

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

In my app I do not want to show keyboard even when UITextfield is firstresponder.Can anyone know how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a UITextField (or other text entry UIControl subclass) is that when it's firstResponder, it's all set to receive text entry.

If you're paired with a bluetooth keyboard, the device won't show a soft keyboard, because the field is set up to receive text entry from the physical keyboard. If you're not, then it's going to show a soft keyboard so you can enter text. That's just how it works.

It could be that what you mean by "first responder" isn't really what you mean. Can you say some more about what you want to accomplish here?

Comment: Yes this exactly I want.I want to connect scanner to my device and want to display the scanned data in textfield because I know scanner act as keyboard to the device connected through bluetooth.Is there any other way to get the scanned data?If there please let me know, now I am using textfield.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the UITextField's inputView to a zero-size view, like this

```
textField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```